# Spectrogram of two audio files (Added together)

Tags: audio, fft, spectrogram

Assume for a moment I have two input signals `f1` and `f2`. I could add these signals to produce a third signal `f3 = f1 + f2`. I would then compute the spectrogram of `f3` as `log(|stft(f3)|^2)`.

Unfortunately I don't have the original signals `f1` and `f2`. I have, however, their spectrograms `A = log(|stft(f1)|^2)` and `B = log(|stft(f2)|^2)`. What I'm looking for is a way to approximate `log(|stft(f3)|^2)` as closely as possible using `A` and `B`. If we do some math we can derive:

`log(|stft(f1 + f2)|^2) = log(|stft(f1) + stft(f2)|^2)`

express `stft(f1) = x1 + i * y1` & `stft(f2) = x2 + i * y2` to write

`... = log(|x1 + i * y1 + x2 + i * y2|^2)`

`... = log((x1 + x2)^2 + (y1 + y2)^2)`

`... = log(x1^2 + x2^2 + y1^2 + y2^2 + 2 * (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2))`

`... = log(|stft(f1)|^2 + |stft(f2)|^2 + 2 * (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2))`

So at this point I could use the approximation:

`log(|stft(f3)|^2) ~ log(exp(A) + exp(B))`

but I would ignore the last part `2 * (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2)`. So my question is: Is there a better approximation for this?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Square magnitude operation is not linear, and as a result you will get a cross term which is not separable (as you've found out).

Comment: So there is no way around? Do you know of any clever approximation? Or something that I could use because I'm dealing with real-world audio files?

Comment: If the two inputs are uncorrelated, the cross term will vanish.

Comment: I guess there are not. One is an audio recording of a specific event and one is an audio recording of background sounds. Since they are both real world recording there should be at least some correlation. But maybe I can just try to ignore the whole cross term (x1*x2 + y1*y2) and see if the rest of the framework still behaves well. I would rather have some sort of linear approximation but it seems hard to find one.

Comment: I really don't get what the actual question is. You have the 2 signals (real amplitude in time), you have the sum, what keeps you from plotting a spectrogram on all three (f1,f2,f1+f2) ?

Comment: For some reason I only want to use the spectrogram I have for f1 and for f2. Imagine that getting the audio signal (for f1 and f2) is super expensive. So I want to compute the spectrogram for f3=f1+f2 without using the original audio signal.

Comment: Then just add them and then transform as you did. Or FT them, then add, then square. As others pointed out the FT is linear but taking the intensity (abs value squared or z* z) is not. But you have all data if you have f1 and f2. I still don't understand the actual question. It would be different if you had say only the FT squared of f1 and of (f1+f2) and you wanted to regenerate f2. But you already have all info at the amplitude level (real in time, complex in FT). Adding two time signals is not expensive, neither in time domain, nor after FT (before ^2). So I'd try to reword the question.

Comment: okay so I rewrote the question. Hopefully it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% understanding your notation but I'll give it a shot. Addition in the time domain corresponds to addition in the frequency domain. Adding two time domain signals x1 and x2 produces a 3rd time domain signal x3. x1, x2 and x3 all have a frequency domain spectrum, F(x1), F(x2) and F(x3). F(x3) is also equal to F(x1) + F(x2) where the addition is performed by adding the real parts of F(x1) to the real parts of F(x2) and adding the imaginary parts of F(x1) to the imaginary parts of F(x2).  So if x1[0] is 1+0j and x2[0] is 0.5+0.5j then the sum is 1.5+0.5j. Judging from your notation you are trying to add the magnitudes, which with this example would be |1+0j| + |0.5+0.5j| = sqrt(1*1) + sqrt(0.5*0.5+0.5*0.5) = sqrt(2) + sqrt(0.5).  Obviously not the same thing.  I think you want something like this:

```
log((|stft(a) + stft(b)|)^2) = log(|stft(a)|^2) + log(|stft(b)|^2)
```

Comment: I rewrote my question to make it more clear where I have the problem. I think you understood my question correctly but your last line seems wrong. The absolute operator is not linear, right?

Comment: I got a question on dsp.stackexchange (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62645/mixing-signal-with-noise-in-frequency-space-stft) which you might be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take the exp() of the 2 log magnitudes, add them, then take the log of the sum.

Comment: I'm doing that right now but it is not correct. I'm missing the cross term 2*(x1*x2 + y1*y2). I think the approximation might be good enough but if you have something that's a bit closer to the truth I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back from the math for a minute, we can see that at a fundamental level, this just isn't possible.

- Consider a 1st signal f1 that is a pure tone at frequency F and amplitude A.
- Consider a 2nd signal f2 that is a pure tone at frequency F and amplitude A, but perfectly out of phase with f1.

In this case, the spectrograms of f1 & f2 are identical.

Now consider two possible combined signals.

- f1 added to itself is a pure tone at frequency F and amplitude 2A.
- f1 added to f2 is complete silence.

From the spectrograms of f1 and f2 alone (which are identical), you've no way to know which of these very different situations you're in.  And this doesn't just hold for pure tones.  Any signal and its reflection about the axis suffer the same problem.  Generalizing even further, there's just no way to know how much your underlying signals cancel and how much they reinforce each other.  That said, there are limits.  If, for a particular frequency, your underlying signals had amplitudes A1 and A2, the biggest possible amplitude is A1+A2 and the smallest possible is abs(A1-A2).